# Where to find BLE GATT specification xml in 2020?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt

When to build BLE related app, it seems that it's essential to have detail information from GATT XML specifications.

When I look for the XML files, I always end up going to [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/), but there is no XML I can find on the page.
Then I later found [this page](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/removed/), saying their XML viewer is no longer maintained and check the "XML files directly", but I still don't see any links to the XMLs.

So far the best I found are

- [github repo](https://github.com/oesmith/gatt-xml) but this one is pretty old
- [xml viewer?](https://www.bluetooth.com/xml-viewer/?src=https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/Sitecore-Media-Library/Gatt/Xml/Services/org.bluetooth.service.environmental_sensing.xml#tree0:0,7%7C0,8%7C0,9,0%7C0,9,1%7C0,9,2%7C0,9,3%7C0,9,4%7C0,9,5%7C0,10%7C0,11,0%7C0,11,1%7C0,12;) but this is only one part of the many
- [specs](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/) but they are not XML files

Where is the central source for the XML files they are talking about?

Comment: In fact you do not need XML for that. Just a specification is required. XML used by some vendors (for example BLED112 can use XML files for GATT configuration) but that varies.

Comment: https://github.com/oesmith/gatt-xml

Comment: If you are looking for machine-readable format you can find json at https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/bluetooth-numbers-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bluetooth SIG seem to be moving away from having the details in an XML format. I find myself using the following documents to find the information I am looking for:

"GATT Specification Supplement" at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/

"16-bit UUID Numbers Document" at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/

Comment: Thanks, but if they are the only references we can look at, how do we go about finding detail like this one?

https://shorturl.at/fmJZ8

requirement, format, decimalexponent and so on

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/environmental-sensing-service-characteristics/

Like, looking at this page doesn't really give me information about this service.  It only has a list of characteristic "names".

Comment: I would suggest you contact the Bluetooth SIG with your feedback. As this question has been closed, if you have a specific question about finding decoding some values then open a new question with that and I'll try to help.